# Unity randomly change image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am using Unity. I want to change the image randomly, maybe by pressing a button or trigger an event.

I can think of a solution like this:

```
    public Image randomImage;
    public Sprite s0;
    public Sprite s1;
    public Sprite s2;
    public Sprite s3;
    public Sprite[] images;
    void Start(){
        images = new Sprite[4];
        images [0] = s0;
        images [1] = s1;
        images [2] = s2;
        images [3] = s3;
     }
    void changeImage(){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int num = rnd.Next(0, 4);
        randomImage <Image> ().sprite = images[num];
        }
```

Then I can drag the sprite that I want to change into *randomImage* , and drag four image into s0, s1, s2, s3. 
However, the number of images I want to choose from is much larger than 4, maybe 20. I don't know whether there is a smarter way to do so instead of creating 20 variables and drag 20 images into it. 
Thank you.

Comment: Declaring `s0`, `s1`, `s2` and `s3` is not necessary here since the  `images` array will be serialized, allowing you to drag & drop directly your sprites in the inspector.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't aware of this. @Hellium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`UnityEngine.Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html). That's it. You don't have to create a new instance of it.

Since array starts from `0`, pass `0` to the first parameter and the array length to the second parameter. The second parameter is exclusive so, you won't get the out of range exception.

There is no need for `randomImage <Image> ()` because `randomImage`  is already an Image(`public Image randomImage;`). You should do that if `randomImage` is GameObject or any other type.

```
public Image randomImage;
public Sprite s0;
public Sprite s1;
public Sprite s2;
public Sprite s3;
public Sprite[] images;

void Start()
{
    images = new Sprite[4];
    images[0] = s0;
    images[1] = s1;
    images[2] = s2;
    images[3] = s3;
}

void changeImage()
{
    int num = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, images.Length);
    randomImage.sprite = images[num];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will use this random function. And I think I don't have to declare s0,s1...too, according to Hellium's  comment.

Comment: Yes, you don't have to since they are all type of `Sprites`. Just remove everything inside the `Start` function then drag each one to the images(Sprite) array in the Editor. The only time you may need the method you have now is when you want to dynamically set the amount of sprites from code then you should not use Editor.